# Xcode swift ui error 'KeyPathComparator' is only available in macOS 12.0 or newer

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

[image]

I am getting this error, as you can see from the image I already do what it tells me how to correct the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried with just 12 ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry bad and wrong  idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are looking to do is not possible.

The compiler error is generated because the compiler cannot apply `@available` attributes to properties which have a property wrapper applied to them. However, even if you remove the `@State` property wrapper and instead wrap the property in a `State` manually, like this

```
@available(macOS 12, *) private var sortOrder = State(wrappedValue: [KeyPathComparator(\Repository.name)])
```

you get a different compiler error:

> Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

So as the new compiler error tells you, you cannot mark stored properties as `@available` without marking the enclosing type `@available`.

To resolve the issue, you need to create 2 versions of your `View`, 1 that's marked `@available(macOS 12, *)` and contains the `KeyPathComparator` and another one without the `@available` that doesn't contain the `KeyPathComparator` property.

Comment: I hadn't noticed anything in the documentation, the example he did was like I did.

Comment: I have a table like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojbSe.png

With: `@State private var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Repository.name)]`

Why is the only field that sorts is owner?

Comment: @Paul there's no example on using `KeyPathComparator` on an older macOS version in the documentation, so not sure what you are referring to. If you have issues with getting `KeyPathComparator` working on macOS 12, you should ask a new question with all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. This question is specifically about `@available` and `@State` not working together.